# List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Obj>' in type cast

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to create dynamic drop down, whose values are populating from one of the lookup table using micro-services, but i have tried same in many ways till now i have not succeed for making it work. as i am totally new to dart/flutter
So can anyone please identify what i have done wrong in below code

**below code is for calling webservice**

```
Future<List<CountryDropDownList>> getCountriesDetails(String url) async{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    // request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    print("request data "+request.toString());
    HttpClientResponse microServicesResponse= await request.close();
    String microServicesResponseString = await microServicesResponse.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    final parsed = await json.decode(microServicesResponseString).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    httpClient.close();
    print("Data Recieved   "+microServicesResponseString.toString());
    return parsed
        .map<CountryDropDownList>(
            (json) => CountryDropDownList.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  }
```

Here is my object type

```
class CountryDropDownList{

  String countryName;
  List<StateDropDownList> stateDropDownList;


  CountryDropDownList({this.countryName, this.stateDropDownList});

  factory CountryDropDownList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CountryDropDownList(
      countryName: json['countryName'] as String,
      stateDropDownList: json['states'] as List<StateDropDownList>,
    );
  }
}
```

**and just for displaying as of now running below code**

```
    class CenterFoundationSubmission extends StatefulWidget  {
      CenterFoundationSubmission({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _CenterFoundationSubmissionState createState() => new _CenterFoundationSubmissionState();
    }

    class _CenterFoundationSubmissionState extends State<CenterFoundationSubmission> {

      NetworkUtil _netUtil = new NetworkUtil();

      var url = "SomeUrl";

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        setState(() {
        });
      }


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var futureBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
          future: _getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return new Text('loading...');
              default:
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Exception here is : ${snapshot.error}');
                else
                  return createView(context, snapshot);
            }
          },
        );

        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Center Foundation"),
          ),
          body: futureBuilder,
        );

      }

      Future<List<CountryDropDownList>> _getData() async {
        List<CountryDropDownList> values = new List<CountryDropDownList>();
        values.addAll(_netUtil.getCountriesDetails(url) as List<CountryDropDownList>);

/*Error Added here , i am getting error while casting list to my object type*/


        await new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 10));

        return values;
      }

      Widget createView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        List<CountryDropDownList> values = snapshot.data;
        return new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: values.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(values[index].countryName),
                  subtitle:  new Text(values[index].stateDropDownList[index].statesName),
                  trailing:   new Text(values[index].stateDropDownList[index].districtDropDownList[index].districtsName),
                ),
                new Divider(height: 2.0,),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

What i have done i have tried calling webservices in multiple ways for calling it, Tried casting services response directly using JSON string response and may thing i have tried.

Could you please help here, help will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you highlight the line that the error happened?

Comment: done just search with his "Error Added here "

Comment: Check if changing ".toList();" to ".toList<CountryDropDownList>();" solves the problem.

Comment: no, No such method at runtime

Comment: Try this: values.addAll(await _netUtil.getCountriesDetails(url) as List<CountryDropDownList>);

Comment: isse was in my json parsing , just by chnaging this line this is resolved,stateDropDownList: json['states'].cast<StateDropDownList>(), but still life is tough , i am able to parse data but now it is not getting displayed, could you please let me know which point is better point to call a webservice in flutter?

Comment: i mean that what if i want to hit service for one time only on widget load and what if multiple time in background?

Comment: I still think you should put that await before your service call.it's future and should be called with await(or then). And about calling service, do you mean you want to call webservice once and use the data multiple times? If else update me, I will put a complete answer here.

Comment: i want onload explanation with future, and where exactly(position) i  have to call my webservice, i am creating dropdown from webservices response which i am populating my dropdown  , if you have some url with good resource or you can help in this then appritiated .thanks

Comment: I would create a singleton instance for CountryDropDownList (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12649574/3123267). you used a futureBuilder for the entire widget which is a proper way. the widget requires the data and it shouldn't show the dropdown until the data is present. So in conclusion, the position of the webservice is fine, If you use the singleton instance pattern.

Comment: ok letme try this. with singleton object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try `List.from()` constructor? Here is a link to the same:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/List.from.html

```
      stateDropDownList: List<StateDropDownList>.from(json['states']);
```