# Strange behavior in Dart singleton

Tags: dart

I wanted to some singleton class and implemented. I referred this article https://stackoverflow.com/a/12649574/6323093 .

My implementation is like this. All source files are same `lib` directory.

Singleton.dart

```
class Singleton {
    static final instance = Singleton();
    int value = 0;
}
```

user1.dart

```
import 'singleton.dart'; // non-package expression

int getValue1() {
    return Singleton.instance.value;
}

setValue1(int val) {
  Singleton.instance.value = val;
}
```

user2.dart

```
import 'package:singleton/singleton.dart'; // package expression

int getValue2() {
    return Singleton.instance.value;
}

setValue2(int val) {
  Singleton.instance.value = val;
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'user1.dart';
import 'user2.dart';

// below is test code
setValue1(99)
setValue2(999)
// My expected behavior is both '999'... why??
print(getValue1()) // -> 99
print(getValue2()) // -> 999
```

In above code, I expected `getValue1()` and `getValue2()` are both `999` but actual results are `99` and `999`.

When I change `user2.dart`'s import statement to `import 'singleton.dart` or `user1.dart`'s import statement to `'package:singleton/singleton.dart';`, results are `999` (as I expected).

Is this correct Dart's behavior? Or this behavior is bug?

I'm confusing because I thought both import expressions, package and non-package, are exact same meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import 'user1.dart';
import 'user2.dart';
```

is likely the culprit.

Relative import in `lib/main.dart` are know to cause such issues.

Change them to

```
import 'package:my_flutter_project/user1.dart';
import 'package:my_flutter_project/user2.dart';
```

and it should work as expected.

Relative imports are fine in other files.

The related Dart issue is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33076
A fix should be work in progress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Now I understand this behavior is not my fault. I'll keep watching this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when spelling the imports wrong:

```
import 'backend/backend.dart';
import 'backend/Backend.dart';
```

Turns out that they both deliver different instances (!)