# Flutter /Dart Classes

Tags: dart, flutter

I have implemented a class in a file user_service.dart:

```
class UserService { 
    Future<User> createUser(...)

 ....
}
```

I have tried referencing the createUser method in another class

I import the User Service class

```
  import 'user_service.dart';
```

and try

```
  UserService userService;
  print(userService.toString());

  UserService.createUser(....);
```

It compiles fine.

A am getting an error:
  NoSuchMethodError: The method 'createUser' was called on null.

Any ideas?

Help appreciated.

Comment: To access `createUser` you need an instance from `UserService` `UserService()` creates an instance. `UserService().createUser()` would work. If you don't want multiple `UserService` instances, you need to create it on a single place and pass it around or use something like a singleton pattern. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart

Comment: If you need to access createUser() method from the class UserService you can declare your method as a static member like this` static Future<User> createUser(...) ;`

Comment: Have you create an instance of that class? ```UserService service = UserService(); service.createUser()```

Comment: Did not create the instance - thank you. Using a singleton is also a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you need firstly create a new instance of you UserService class.

```
UserService _instance = UserService(); // here you are creating a new instance with a default constructor

//now you can call your UserService methods
_instance.createUser();
```