# How to implement Singleton pattern in Dart using factory constructors?

Tags: constructor, dart, singleton, factory, factory-pattern

I'm trying to implement the singleton pattern in a database helper class, but, I can't seem to understand the purpose of a factory constructor and if there's an alternative method to using it.

```
class DbHelper {

         final String tblName ='';
         final String clmnName ='';
         final String clmnPass='';

         DbHelper._constr();
         static final DbHelper _db = new DbHelper._constr();

         factory DbHelper(){ return _db;}  

         Database _mydb;
         Future<Database> get mydb async{

         initDb() {
          if(_mydb != null)
          {
              return _mydb;
          }
          _mydb = await  initDb();
          return _mydb;
         }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use the factory constructor.
The factory constructor was convenient when `new` was not yet optional because then it `new MyClass()` worked for classes where the constructor returned a new instance every time or where the class returned a cached instance. It was not the callers responsibility to know how and when the object was actually created.

You can change

```
factory DbHelper(){ return _db;}
```

to

```
DbHelper get singleton { return _db;}
```

and acquire the instance using

```
var mySingletonReference = DbHelper.singleton;
```

instead of

```
var mySingletonReference = DbHelper();
```

It's just a matter of preference.

Comment: so it's either use a static singleton property or use a factory pattern. correct?

Comment: You can also change `static final DbHelper _db = new DbHelper._constr();` to `static final DbHelper singleton = new DbHelper._constr();` and remove the `singleton` getter I suggested in my answer. It depends on your use case. You might not be able to use a field initializer if you need additional config values to create the instance. In your example it would be sufficient though.

Comment: I'm not really understanding. A full example (or a link to one) would be really helpful. I also don't understand how the use cases affect it.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26044729/3681880) what you are talking about? So it is just a matter of preference? Both have the same effect?

Comment: Yes it's only a matter of preference.

Comment: I expanded my questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057958/comparing-ways-to-create-singletons-in-dart