# How to access to provider field from class that do not have context?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using `Provider`. I have got two classes: `class TenderApiData {}` it's stand alone class (not widget). How I can write `accesstoken` to `AppState`?

```
class AppState extends ChangeNotifier // putted to ChangeNotifierProvider
{ 
  String _accesstoken; // need to fill not from widget but from stand alone class
  String _customer; // Fill from widget 
  List<String> _regions; // Fill from widget 
  List<String> _industry; // Fill from widget 
  ...
}
```

I need way to read\write `accesstoken` from stand alone classes.

Or I have issue with architecture of my app?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/bubnenkoff/0aaf86f31361fdb20f2d57db86225e92) is full source code.

Comment: how did you finally achieve it? i do have a similar requirement

Comment: Consider using riverpod instead of Provider.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot and should not access providers outside of the widget tree.

Even if you could theoretically use globals/singletons or an alternative like `get_it`, **don't do that**.

You will instead want to use a widget to do the bridge between your provider, and your model.

This is usually achieved through the `didChangeDependencies` life-cycle, like so:

```dart
class MyState extends State<T> {
  MyModel model = MyModel();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    model.valueThatComesFromAProvider = Provider.of<MyDependency>(context);
  }
}
```

`provider` comes with a widget built-in widgets that help with common scenarios, that are:

- `ProxyProvider`
- `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`

A typical example would be:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<TenderApiData, AppState>(
  initialBuilder: () => AppState(),
  builder: (_, tender, model) => model
    ..accessToken = tender.accessToken,
  child: ...,
);
```

Comment: In the first two lines you state, "You should not access providers outside of the widget tree" even if theoretically possible. Instead of a blatant "**don't do that**", can you say why?

Comment: How do you reset state of app during testing without accessing those classes?

Comment: Contrary to this advice (maybe it's a later development?) the description of the `read()` function in `provider.dart` actively encourages passing it to objects that need access to the provider but have no context.

Comment: Does this mean that we should not use Providers with MVC architecture? If the provider should be in the Model and listened from the Controller, but we can't access to context from the Controller since it doesn't have a context

Answer (score 10):

#### TL;DR

Swap `provider` for `get_it`. The later does DI globally without scoping it to a BuildContext. (It actually has its own optional scoping mechanism using string `namedInstance`'s.)

#### The rest...

I ran into a similar problem and I believe it comes down to the fact that Provider enforces a certain type of (meta?) architecture, namely one where Widgets are at the top of what you might call the "agency pyramid".

In other words, in this style, widgets are knowledgable about Business Logic (hence the name BLoC architecture), they run the show, not unlike the `ViewController` paradigm popularised by iOS and also maybe MVVM setups.

In this architectural style, when a widget creates a child widget, it also creates the model for the widget. Here context could be important, for example, if you had multiple instances of the same child widget being displayed simultaneously, each would need its own instance of the underlying model. Within the widget or its descendents, your DI system would need the Context to select the proper one. See `BuildContext::findAncestorWidgetOfExactType` to get an idea why/how.

This architectural style is the one seemingly encouraged by plain vanilla Flutter, with its paradigms of app-as-a-widget ("turtles all the way down"), non-visual widgets, layout-as-widgets and InheritedWidget for DI (which provider uses I believe)

BUT

Modern app frameworks libs (e.g. redux, mobx) encourage *the opposite* kind of meta-architecture: widgets at the bottom of the pyramid.

Here widgets are "dumb", just UI signal generators and receivers. The business logic is encapsulated in a "Store" or via "Actions" which interact with a store. The widgets just react to the relevant fields on the store being updated and send Action signals when the user interacts with them.

### Which should you use?

In my experience, at least on mobile where the screen realestate is less, scoping a model to a branch in the render tree is seldom required. If it suddenly becomes important then there are plenty of other ways to handle it (indexed array, id lookup map, namedInstances in `get_it`) than to require linking it to the semantics of UI rendering.

Currently, having spent too much time in iOS ViewControllers, I'm a fan of new systems which enforce better [SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). And personally find Flutter's everything-is-a-widget pardigm to appear a bit messy at times if left untended. But ultimately it's a personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

you can use navigator key

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

and put this key in MaterialApp and wrap it with your provider (TenderApiData)

```
  ChangeNotifierProvider<TenderApiData>(
              create: (_) => TenderApiData(),
              child: Consumer<TenderApiData>(builder: (context, tenderApiData , child) {
                return  MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    
                        title: 'title',
                      home: SplashScreen());
              }),
            );
```

and listen to this provider from anywhere with this navigator key

```
navigatorKey.currentContext?.read<TenderApiData>();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that does not use `GetIt` or `GlobalKey`.
It uses the [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart) design pattern.

For instance:

```
class BackgroundTaskProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  static final BackgroundTaskProvider _backgroundTaskProvider = BackgroundTaskProvider._internal();

  factory BackgroundTaskProvider() {
    return _backgroundTaskProvider;
  }

  BackgroundTaskProvider._internal();

  List<Task> backgroundTasks = [];
  
  addBackgroundTask(Task task) {
    backgroundTasks.add(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Than you could do something like:

```
BackgroundTaskProvider().addBackgroundTask(Task()));
```

from everywhere in your code. **Be aware** use with caution make sure to understand the singleton pattern and its pro's and cons.

### Motivation

I agree with the answer from Rémi Rousselet that Singleton and GetIt should not be used generally. However, I found my self wanting to add something to the provider across an asynchronous gap. Something like:

```
Task task = await getSomeTask();
BackgroundTaskProvider provider = Provider.of<MyDependency>(context);
if(mounted) provider.addToBackgroundTasks(task);
```

If the state is not mounted anymore, the task end up not being added to the state of the BackGroundTask provider.