# Should use Provider if I have few classes for processing data?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I read docs, and looked a lot of examples, but still can't understand should I use `Provider` if I need access to data in several classes. The main problem -- `context` that do not exists outside widgets.

So probably I do not understand conception of Provider? Here small example what I mean:

```
class A
{
String foo;
}
```

and

```
class B
{
 String x;
 Provider<A>.of(context).foo = "aaa";
}
```

I faced with this problem and I do not know how to resolve it.

Comment: What didn't you understand in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415617/how-to-access-to-provider-field-from-class-that-do-not-have-context/57416260#57416260?

Comment: @RémiRousselet If I facing with such problem am I use Provider wrong?

Comment: Yes. You should never need to read from a provider from another class. Instead the value is injected

Comment: @RémiRousselet but what I should to do if I want to process data in separate class outside widget?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and i found the solution in this package [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) , you can access the instance of the class without using provider and you don't need context, however provider is used to link between your business logic and the UI , so you should use provider.of(context) in the ui not in your logic, but i think this package will help you