# Question about Global Variable in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing app in flutter.
I want to store width and height of a screen in a variable using media query and want to use it globally in whole app. How to do this?

Comment: You can create a singleton check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart)

Comment: I use the belt and braces approach, I have a 'global_configs.dart' code file that contains all the variables I need to reference across the app (those not handled by scoped_model). I just import it in to all other .dart files that need it. Singletons and inherited widgets are something I will look at later...using the 'kiss' approach to get things working

Comment: That information is already available globally. Simply import `dart:ui` and read `window`

Answer (score 2):

**Create a class Common.dart**

```
class Common{
  static  int WIDTH;
  static  int HEIGHT;
}
```

In your page class, set WIDTH and HEIGHT and access from all classes.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Common.WIDTH = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; //set width to static variable
  Common.HEIGHT = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;//set height to static variable
  }
```

Getting WIDTH and HEIGHT

```
 var tempWidth =  Common.WIDTH;  
 var tempHeight =  Common.HEIGHT;
```