# Flutter: How to start playing music in loop using audioplayers package on start of app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development

I want to continuously play music in my app on loop similar to many game apps available on the store.

However I am not sure when to initialize the music loop start and how to stop it.
I created a class which contains the logic to start and stop the music.

Also My App Structure is like this

Main.dart

Wrapper.dart

#### (Here is where I did try initializing Audioplayer this is called to check login so a new instance of the player is created and the music overlaps)

>> Signin.dart

#### (If not signed in redirects here)

>> Home.dart

#### (If signed in redirects here)

```
class Music {
    AudioCache cache; 
    AudioPlayer player; 

    void _playFile() async{
      player = await cache.play('my_audio.mp3'); 
    }

    void _stopFile() {
      player?.stop(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see you have created a Music class. But that is not a singleton class. So, every time you are getting a new instance. What you need is a [singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55348216/7722745). You can implement something like this:

```
class Music {
  AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
  AudioCache cache = AudioCache();

  Music._privateConstructor() {
    this.player.setVolume(0.5);
  }

  static final Music instance = Music._privateConstructor();

  Future playLoop(String filePath) async {
    player.stop();
    player = await cache.loop(filePath);
  }

  void stopLoop() {
    player?.stop();
  }
}
```

This guarantees that every time you gets the same instance.

Also, you need to manage the states properly as well.

#### [AppLifecycleState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html)

There are basically 4 types of states, these are:

- **resumed**: The application is visible and responding to user input.
- **inactive**: The application is in an inactive state and is not receiving user input.
- **paused**: The application is not currently visible to the user, not responding user input, and running in the background.
- **detached**: The application is still hosted on a flutter engine but is detached from any host views.

You can `@override` the `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` method.

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if ((state == AppLifecycleState.paused ||
            state == AppLifecycleState.detached ||
            state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) &&
        musicOn) {
      audio.stopLoop();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed && musicOn) {
      audio.playLoop("loop.mp3");
    }
  }
```

This prevents the overlap of music when you minimize and reopens apps.

Comment: Hi @sn- sorry did not see your answer and returned to this after a long time.So does the didChangeAppLifecycleState code have to be in all the different screens?

Comment: Hi Teknoville, did you figure out the question you asked about didChangeAppLigeCycleState needing to be in all the screens?