# dart: Will objects created in a recurring function be cached or recreated?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart, optimization

In recurring functions such as `CustomPaint()`'s `paint()`, if I create an object this way:

```dart
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
  ....
  
  var myObj = MyClass();
  var myObj.configure(canvas, size);
 
  ....
    
}
```

Will this object get recreated while `paint()` gets called every frame
or will it be cached until something it depends on such as screen size changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you implement MyClass constructor. I can see several options:

- MyClass standard constructor - then object will be recreated every time it is called;
- MyClass can have const constructor. Then if you create instance with `const MyClass()` it will be same instance. Therefore it is not always possible to do that.
- MyClass can have default factory constructor. This way you can implement "caching" inside MyClass itself depending on your requirements. Example is "singleton" - you will always have single instance. See here for example: [How do you build a Singleton in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart)

Please note also that if objects of MyClass are lightweight it could be that you do not need to optimize: Dart is usually good creating lots of small objects and garbage collecting them.