# How to cache a value returned by a Future?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

For my Flutter app I'm trying to access a `List` of `Notebooks`, this list is parsed from a file by the `Api`. I would like to avoid reading/parsing the file every time I call my notebooks getter, hence I would like something like this:

- if the file had already been parsed once, return the previously parsed `List<Note>` ;
- else, read and parse the file, save the `List<Note>` and returns it.

I imagine something like this :

```dart
  List<Notebook> get notebooks {
    if (_notebooks != null) {
      return _notebooks;
    } else {
      return await _api.getNotebooks();
    }
  }
```

This code is not correct because I would need to mark the getter `async` and return a Future, which I don't want to. Do you know any solution for this problem, like caching values ? I also want to avoid initializing this list in my app startup and only parse once the first time the value is needed.

Comment: Your operation ultimately depends on an asynchronous operation.  Either you will need a separate asynchronous initialization step somewhere or the caching getter will need to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a singleton and you can store the data inside a property once you read it, from next time onwards you can use the same from the property.

You can refer this question to create a singleton

[How do you build a Singleton in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart)