# How set and use global variable in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

On main.dart I get response from api username and set `String myUsername = 'stackoverflow';

How on all page use **myUsername** as global variable?

Comment: Check provider package for state management or create a singleton class ...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Singleton like this:

```
class SingletonTest{
  String myUsername;

  SingletonTest._private();

  static SingletonTest _instance = SingletonTest._private();
  static SingletonTest get instance => _instance;
}
```

After that, you can access it from anywhere in your code using:

```
var singl = SingletonTest.instance;
```

For more examples refer to:

[How to build a Singleton in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart)

Or you can use Provider Pattern, more info about it here:

[Provider Pattern](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/provider-pattern-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 1):

the answer above is right ,
however if you don't want to make a singleton class,
all you can do is, save it to shared preference, using the
[shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

myPreference.setString("userName", Your user name)

and get it using

myPreference.getString("userName")