# what is wrong here? (_instance' has not been initialized)

Tags: flutter, dart

How I can initialize _instance?

I get "Field '_instance' has not been initialized"
Or any other ways to get rid of nullSafety,,,

here is the code:

```
   class ShoppingBasketData{ 
  static late ShoppingBasketData _instance ;
  
   late List<product> _basketItem;


  ShoppingBasketData(){
    _basketItem =<product>[];
  }

  List<product> get basketItem => _basketItem;

  set basketItem(List<product> value) {
    _basketItem = value;
  }

  static  ShoppingBasketData getInstance(){
    if (_instance == null){
      _instance  = ShoppingBasketData();
      
    }
    return _instance;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: when you declare `late` keyword you need to initialize it that's why you got the error.

Comment: but when I remove late I get this error :"The non-nullable variable '_instance' must be initialized"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong is that you declared `_instance` to be `late`. What that means is that you as a developer promise to initialize it before you access it. If you break that promise, you get an exception.

It seems that you want `null` to be a valid value, so what you need to do is make it nullable:

```
static ShoppingBasketData? _instance
```

You may also want to look into [How do you build a Singleton in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart) so you don't have to reinvent the wheel, and you may want to look into [Flutter state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt), because singleton is probably the worst of all options.

Comment: thanks I did So, but its another error : """ A value of type 'ShoppingBasketData?' can't be returned from the method 'getInstance' because it has a return type of 'ShoppingBasketData'.""    what else I can do?

Comment: You could use a `!` since you know it's not null, `return _instance!;` but you should really look into alternatives to your singleton alltogether. Or at least a better Singleton pattern. See the links I added.

Comment: Thannnnnnksssss!!!! It solved it!!!