# Flutter & Dart: How to play multiple sounds at the same time in app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I have the below code where the function **clickSound** just plays a simple button click sound audio without any loop and the function **loopSound** plays music in a loop.However I am unable to play both at the same time i.e. (in case the music is playing and I want to click a button for example).

How can I implement that using the same instance or will I have to create two instances and change my code from being a singleton?

Note: I am using the **audioplayers ** package

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:biblequiz/services/preferences.dart';

class AudioService {
  AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  static final AudioService instance = AudioService._();

  AudioService._() {
    this.player.setVolume(1.0);
  }

  void clickSound() async {
    await player.play(AssetSource('sounds/click.mp3'));      
  }

  void loopSound() async {
      player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);
      await player.play(AssetSource('sounds/music.wav'));
  }

  void stopLoop() async {
    await player.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to play the song and play on loop with a single click ? or after playing the song, want to set on loop ?

Comment: @SapinderSingh The song will be playing as background music as its a game app.But I also want to play a click sound on clicking a button as the user navigates the  game.Currently the music looping is stopped if I play the click sound.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new instance of `AudioPlayer` for each new sound you want to play. [audioplayers getting started](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/getting_started.md)

Also, your singleton is not complete [dart singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart). What about just static methods? [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

```
  import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class AudioService {
  static AudioPlayer loopPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  static void loopSound(String src, double volume) async {
    loopPlayer.setVolume(volume);
    loopPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);
    await loopPlayer.play(AssetSource(src));
  }

  static void stopLoop() async {
    await loopPlayer.stop();
  }

  static void clickSound(String src, double volume) async {
    AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
    player.setVolume(volume);
    await player.play(AssetSource(src));
  }
}
```