Flutter eager vs lazy singletons. Loading and instantiation
I understand the difference between eager and lazy singletons: the eager is instantiated when it first loaded, but the lazy is instantiated when it is first used (method called).
Now, to fully understand the difference we should know when loading happens.
According to this article, it happens in the Starting the Dart VM phase. Just before Creating and running a Dart Isolate phase when the main method is called.
The question is: when we call singleton from main
void main() async{
  await MyService().execute();
  runApp( MainApp());
}

there is practically no difference between eager and lazy. Am I right?
Update.
Implementations of eager(early) and lazy singletons.
Eager:
class MyService{
  MyService._();
  static final _instance = MyService._();
  factory MyService() => _instance;
} 

Lazy:
class MyService{
  MyService._();
  static MyService _instance;
  factory MyService() => _instance ??= MyService();
} 

Update 2.
As was clarified by jamesdin in comments, Dart has lazy initialization for static variables and therefore the first approach is preferable since it is a bit shorter and does not require further null checks.

there's definitely a difference between both approaches, imagine that 'you have implemented Eager singleton = early Singleton and you  never used it' which results in (one unnecessary object in RAM) which is the instance .

All global and static variables in Dart are initialized lazily, so I'm not sure what you mean by an eager singleton.  I also don't follow what the article you linked to has to do with singletons. Can you elaborate?

@A-E Completely agree, but hardly can imagine a scenario when singleton will not be used. Application crash? Closed by user? In both cases, there are no worries about RAM.

@jamesdlin I have updated the question to clarify what I mean by eager and lazy. The article has nothing to do with singletons specifically. It is just the single place I found that specifies when classes are loaded in the Dart app. Would you say that the above code is practically identical, since eager will be initialized lazily anyway?

Your "lazy" version isn't legal.  Even if you fix the declaration to static MyService? _instance;, assuming that nothing else in the library accesses MyService._instance directly and goes only through the factory constructor, there would be no difference in when the object would be initialized.  As I stated before, all global and static variables are already lazy.  That is, they will be initialized the first time they are accessed.  The latter method is unnecessarily verbose and would add extra complication of needing to check for null whenever using _instance.

@jamesdlin. Right. Fixed. (quick copy-paste problem).
Thank you a lot for your clarification. I don't think that this information is widely known. For example, this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649573/how-do-you-build-a-singleton-in-dart has an answer with 87 upvotes, and the implementation as similar to the above (with getter instead of factory). Anyway, my question doesn't make sense anymore. ))) Thanks again.

@jamesdin Would you like to post what you commented as an answer? I think a lot of people lack this knowledge.

Singleton implementation almost always involve global or static variables, but global and static variables are already initialized lazily when they are first accessed.  From the Dart Language tour:

Top-level and class variables are lazily initialized; the initialization code runs the first time the variable is used.

So given your example:

Eager:
class MyService{
  MyService._();
  static final _instance = MyService._();
  factory MyService() => _instance;
} 

Lazy:
class MyService{
  MyService._();
  static MyService? _instance;
  factory MyService() => _instance ??= MyService();
} 


there will be no difference when MyService will be initialized (assuming that everything else uses the MyService factory constructor and does not access MyService._instance directly).  In both cases _instance will be lazily initialized the first time that the factory constructor is explicitly invoked after entering main().  Neither version is actually eager.
The "lazy" version is unnecessarily verbose and adds an extra null-check.  As written, it is not useful.  However, that practice can be useful in situations where you might want to initialize the singleton to something else:
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class MyService{
  MyService._();
  static MyService? _instance;
  factory MyService() => _instance ??= MyService();

  @visibleForTesting
  factory MyService.test(MyService service) {
    _instance = service;
  }
} 

and then tests can explicitly use MyService.test to initialize the singleton to a fake or mock implementation.


The "eager" version is unnecessarily verbose and adds an extra null-check.
Typo: it should be "lazy" instead.


@YuriyN. Oops, yes.  Fixed.
